# Textarea changing text colour when editing it

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have a text area

```css
:root {
    --color-back: #000;
    --color-text: #fff;
}

textarea {
    background-color: var(--color-back);
    color: var(--color-text);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" maxlength="65525" required=""></textarea>
```

When I'm not editing (i.e. cursor not selected inside the text area), the styling is correct. When I start editing it, the font colour changes. Is this possibly platform dependent and unfixable without some JavaScript, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think we're missing some information here. What are the colors you want to see in which state? When editing, white text on black background, and when not editing... ?

Comment: Check out Javascript [activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement).

Comment: @ThomasL. the question is about how to change textarea colours on edit, the colours itself don't matter

Comment: @Cédric Oh OK, I misinterpreted the question. Thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be another style overwriting yours when focusing the `textarea`.

Editing the [:focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) pseudo-class of the `textarea` should solve your problem.

```css
textarea:focus {
    background-color: var(--color-back);
    color: var(--color-text);
}
```

If the problem continues, verify if there is any `*.css` or inline styling in your page overwriting yours.

Snippet:

```html
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" maxlength="65525" required=""></textarea>

<style>
  :root {
    --color-back: #000;
    --color-text: #fff;
  }

  textarea {
    background-color: var(--color-back);
    color: var(--color-text);
  }
  
  textarea:focus {
    background-color: var(--color-back);
    color: var(--color-text);
  }
</style>
```